# Get Data using sql with multi join?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'have these tables and [image]

I want to get the persistence list when the typeAbsence is not null . these my criteria translated in  sql:

```
select *
from   PERSISTENCE prestation0_ 
inner join AgentMJ agentmj1_ on prestation0_.FK_AGENTMJ_ID=agentmj1_.PK_AGENTMJ_ID
inner join Absence absences2_ on agentmj1_.PK_AGENTMJ_ID=absences2_.FK_AGENT_MJ_ID
inner join TypeAbsence typeabsenc3_ on 
absences2_.FK_TYPE_ABSENCE_ID=typeabsenc3_.PK_TYPE_ABSENCE_ID 
where agentmj1_.PK_AGENTMJ_ID=18   and typeabsenc3_.PK_TYPE_ABSENCE_ID=3 ;
```

any help thanks in advance

Comment: Is your SQL not working?

Comment: @Indrew, not getting the right result , looks like this condition is exist or not: inner join TypeAbsence typeabsenc3_ on 
absences2_.FK_TYPE_ABSENCE_ID=typeabsenc3_.PK_TYPE_ABSENCE_ID  , the result is the same

Comment: Could you try a left outer join in your 3rd join and only get where that key is not null.  Something like this?

left outer join TypeAbsence typeabsenc3_ on 
absences2_.FK_TYPE_ABSENCE_ID=typeabsenc3_.PK_TYPE_ABSENCE_ID 

where 
typeabsenc3_.PK_TYPE_ABSENCE_ID IS NOT NULL
AND agentmj1_.PK_AGENTMJ_ID=18   
AND typeabsenc3_.PK_TYPE_ABSENCE_ID=3 ;

Comment: @Vlookup not working , still same result